# text is not showing on toolbar created in mfc?

Tags: c++, mfc

```
int MFC_Tutorial_Window::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
if (CFrameWnd::OnCreate(lpCreateStruct) == -1)
    return -1;

if (!myBar.CreateEx(this, TBSTYLE_FLAT, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | CBRS_TOP
    | CBRS_GRIPPER | CBRS_TOOLTIPS | CBRS_FLYBY | CBRS_SIZE_DYNAMIC))
{
    MessageBox(L"Failed to create toolbar\n");
    return -1; // fail to create
}

CImageList img;
CString str;

myBar.GetToolBarCtrl().SetButtonWidth(150,250);
myBar.GetToolBarCtrl().SetExtendedStyle(TBSTYLE_EX_DRAWDDARROWS);
bool b = img.Create(IDB_COLDBITMAP, 22, 0, RGB(255, 0, 255));
myBar.GetToolBarCtrl().SetHotImageList(&img);

//img.Detach();
myBar.ModifyStyle(0, TBSTYLE_FLAT | TBSTYLE_TRANSPARENT);
myBar.SetButtons(NULL, 5);

myBar.SetButtonInfo(0, IDB_BITMAP1, TBSTYLE_BUTTON |TBSTYLE_DROPDOWN |TBBS_AUTOSIZE , 0);
b = myBar.SetButtonText(0,L"ABC");

myBar.SetSizes(CSize(42,38),CSize(16,15));

myBar.EnableDocking(CBRS_ALIGN_ANY);
EnableDocking(CBRS_ALIGN_ANY);
DockControlBar(&myBar);
}
```

above code is showing toolbar without text.what to do to get
text displayed when i move toolbar from one position to other during runtime but not at first time :(

Answer (score 0):

I believe its just a matter of doing:

```
myBar.SetWindowText( _T( "Window Title goes here" ) );
```

Comment: when i am shifting toolbar from one position to other then text is displaying.... but not at first time

Comment: it  will set the title for toolbar not for button on toolbar.